# SELECT Statement | 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement

Tags: python, mysql

I hope I can seek help here. I've been reading existing questions but can't solve it.

I've been looking online for hours and also revisit my code multiple times but I still can't perform a parameterized SELECT statement in python using mysql connector

I am using the same syntax when I do an INSERT and it is working fine
here is my working INSERT snippet

```
__cursor = __con.cursor(prepared=True)
__cursor.execute(self.query,self.values) 
__con.commit()
```

Then this is my non-working SELECT statement

```
__cursor = __con.cursor(prepared=True)
__cursor.execute(self.query,self.query)
r = __cursor.fetchall()
```

This is the value I am passing at the beginning.

```
#WORKING
params = {"type":"INSERT","query":"INSERT INTO behaviors (behavior_id,behavior_name,related_hosts) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)","values":("xfxsaf","behacior A","host b")}


#NOT WORKING
params= {"type":"SELECT","query":"SELECT %s FROM behaviors where related_hosts = '%s'","values":("behavior_id","host1",)}
#params passed to my Class
self.query = params.query
self.value = params.values
```

What's confusing me is it works on INSERT but not on SELECT. When I put the values directly in the execute method, I get the same issue:

```
__cursor.execute("""SELECT behavior_id FROM behaviors where related_hosts='%s';""",("*","host B"))
```

I have verified that the value is a tuple by printing out isInstance()

Here is what I get from logs

```
  File "C:\Users\jgutierrez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 1208, in execute
raise errors.ProgrammingError(
```

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement
2020-07-01 17:02:02,655 -DEBUG : query.py -  in line number 77 -  DB connection is successfully closed

Comment: `%s` placeholders shouldn't be put inside quotes. Also, you can't use a placeholder for a column name.

Comment: Thank you. 
Tried it but got the same error {"type":"SELECT","query":"SELECT * FROM behaviors where related_hosts = %s","values":("hostB")}

Comment: `__cursor.execute(self.query,self.query)` The second `self.query` should be `self.value`

Comment: Is it `self.value` or `self.values`? I see both in the code you posted.

Comment: oh. right. Thank you. works now. also forgot the comma to make the query tuple  Thank you. {"type":"SELECT","query":"SELECT * FROM behaviors where related_hosts = %s;","values":("corehost",)}

Comment: Of course, I didn't notice that either

Comment: Feel free to add an answer and accept, or otherwise delete (if the 'typos' don't beat you to it)